# position:absolute within a display:inline

Tags: css

I have a setup like this:

```
<div class="item">
  <img src="..."/>
  <span class="item-detail"></span>
  <span class="item-detail"></span>
  <!-- ... -->      
  <span class="item-detail"></span>
</div>
<div class="item"><!-- ... --></div>
<div class="item"><!-- ... --></div>
<!-- ... -->
<div class="item"><!-- ... --></div>
```

Each of the `span`s is positioned absolutely within their `div` (which has `position:relative`), laying within the `img`, so the `div` gets its size from the size of the `img`.

I want to display as many of the `div`s as will fit on a single line.  I could just have the `div`s `float:left`, but I don't like that because

- the `div`s' containing element doesn't get resized by them
- it only prints 1-2 `div`s to a line when physically printed

So a better idea seemed to be to use `display:inline` on the `div`s.  The `img`s still line up correctly, however, now, the absolute positioning for the contained `span`s is now messed up - they appear to be positioned relative to the bottom of their containing `div`, rather than the top  (at least, that's what's happening on Firefox3.6).

What's going on?  How can I get around this?

Comment: For your #1 up there, give the containing element an `overflow: auto` to have it take the floated divs into account in it's sizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `display:inline-block`, this will give you both characteristics for your element.

Comment: awesome, thanks!  Now I just need to figure how to convince my printer that it can fit three `div`s to a line... but you answered my question.  A+

Answer (score 0):

What about adding **another** relative-positioned div *inside* the inline positioned div. This way, the spans will be aligned according to the relative one.